# How to recover multiple values of twig in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, twig

How to recover multiple values ​​of twig in javascript?

**Here is my last try:**

*I manage to display the data in my html thanks to twig:*

```
{% for step in travel.steps %}
   {{ step.latitude }}
   {{ step.longitude }}
{% endfor %}
```

*And here is my try in javascript:*

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var lat = {{ travel.steps.latitude|json_encode() }};
        console.log(lat); //ERROR
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I would assume `travel.steps` is an array as you process it as an array in the for loop. So `travel.steps.latitude` cannot be correct

Comment: Do you want one of the latitudes set to the javascript variable or all of them

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank for your response.  I want all of them for then place them on my gg map

Comment: So what should `lat` look like once this code finishes

Comment: 58.5433677 for example @RiggsFolly

Comment: Thats only ONE value

Comment: my goal is first to have the latitude of the first step, because then, it will be simple with a loop to have all

Comment: `var lat = {{ travel.steps[0].latitude|json_encode() }};`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but why not just do:

```
{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var steps = {{ travel.steps | json_encode() }};
    console.log(steps); 
    //now you can do steps[0].lat or something
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```